# VSTS Build Pipeline: Bundle install task fails

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm completely new to VSTS and its release/build pipelines. I've been following a guide to have VSTS automatically build and deploy my [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) site.

The task fails at the `bundle install` task:

`` 2018-08-20T02:27:17.2704401Z ##[section]Starting: install dependencies
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708156Z ==============================================================================
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708277Z Task         : Command Line
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708381Z Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708506Z Version      : 2.136.0
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708613Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2708768Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2018-08-20T02:27:17.2709048Z ==============================================================================
2018-08-20T02:27:18.1102116Z Generating script.
2018-08-20T02:27:18.1226372Z Script contents:
2018-08-20T02:27:18.1233486Z bundle install
2018-08-20T02:27:18.1838042Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\c2eb18cb-eb2c-459b-8326-58392f545780.cmd""
2018-08-20T02:27:20.5785853Z Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
2018-08-20T02:27:20.5797913Z Ignoring ffi-1.9.25 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.25
2018-08-20T02:27:20.5811063Z Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
2018-08-20T02:27:25.7142354Z Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
2018-08-20T02:27:25.8600906Z Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
2018-08-20T02:27:25.8867390Z Resolving dependencies...
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9863074Z Using public_suffix 3.0.2
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9866608Z Using addressable 2.5.2
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9869556Z Using bundler 1.16.3
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9873954Z Using colorator 1.1.0
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9877018Z Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
2018-08-20T02:27:25.9891240Z Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
2018-08-20T02:27:26.5498918Z Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 (x64-mingw32)
2018-08-20T02:27:27.3971722Z Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
2018-08-20T02:27:27.4135508Z Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0706988Z Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0707433Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0707643Z current directory: D:/a/r1/a/_Experience
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0707862Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708061Z C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/2.5.0/x64/bin/ruby.exe -r
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708210Z ./siteconf20180820-2744-iqcsgd.rb extconf.rb
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708346Z creating Makefile
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708451Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708773Z current directory: D:/a/r1/a/_Experience
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0708924Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709065Z make "DESTDIR=" clean
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709181Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709314Z current directory: D:/a/r1/a/_Experience
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709474Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709611Z make "DESTDIR="
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709769Z generating ruby_http_parser-x64-mingw32.def
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0709902Z compiling ruby_http_parser.c
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710044Z x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe: error:
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710242Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser:
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710383Z No such file or directory
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710519Z make: *** [Makefile:242: ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710625Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710769Z make failed, exit code 2
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0710869Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0711005Z Gem files will remain installed in D:/a/r1/a/_Experience
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0711176Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0711322Z Results logged to D:/a/r1/a/_Experience
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0711507Z Guide/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0712572Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0712723Z An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0712863Z continue.
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713000Z Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0' --source
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713187Z 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713294Z 
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713415Z In Gemfile:
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713579Z   jekyll was resolved to 3.8.3, which depends on
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713724Z     em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.1, which depends on
2018-08-20T02:27:39.0713854Z       http_parser.rb
2018-08-20T02:27:39.4215782Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '5'.
2018-08-20T02:27:39.4727933Z ##[section]Finishing: install dependencies ``

Here's my build pipeline:

1. [use VSTS git as artifact]
2. Use Ruby >= 2.4
3. gem install bundler
4. bundle install
5. bundle exec jekyll build -d $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
6. [publish site to artifacts]

I'm specifying a working directory under Advanced on all tasks as it was failing saying "No Gemfile found" before I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by incorrectly having my `.bundle` directory checked in to the repository.

More info: https://bundler.io/v1.3/rationale.html#checking-your-code-into-version-control

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.